# AWS code deploy agent not able to install?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-code-deploy

Hi i am trying to install code deploy agent in my ec2 agent but not able to succeed
 I m following below steps

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install awscli
sudo apt-get install ruby2.0
cd /home/ubuntu
sudo aws s3 cp s3://bucket-name/latest/install . --region region-name
sudo chmod +x ./install
sudo ./install auto
```

but ./install file is missing for me .
But I dont think its a problem with AMI as I used same steps with same AMI in different ec2 instance. Any one has any idea. please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to fill in the bucket name and region name in `sudo aws s3 cp s3://bucket-name/latest/install . --region region-name`. If you are in us-east-1 you would use: `aws-codedeploy-us-east-1` and `us-east-1`.

All the buckets follow that pattern so you can fill in another region if you are there instead.

See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/how-to-set-up-new-instance.html for a complete list of buckets for each region.